# i want to know unused string consume space or not and why program is run with usused strings

Tags: c, string

i want to know c compiler behavior with strings

i am using windows 7 code block with GCC

```
int main()
 {
"1145"; "ho";
printf("hello");
}
```

so i want to know unused string consume memory space or not

Comment: See the assembler output of your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand l(eft)-values and r(ight)-values. 
l-values actually are memory locations, where objects are stored.
r-values are data, that supposed to be stored in some place in memory (in l-value).

So your construct `"1145"; "ho";`

makes two r-values that are not assigned anywhere. You can even make this (perfectly valid) code:

```
int main(){
;;
    printf("hello");
}
```

This is allowed because `;` is `null statement` operator. You will, not once, see expressions like

```
while(*ptr++);   // ajusts pointer until contents of the pointer become 0
```

where `while` is actually executing every iteration `;`

---

I'm 99% sure that this strings didn't use any space at all, because GCC without any option recognized unused statement and didn't generate any code for this line.

[image: C code]
[image: Compiled code]

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the code shown and assuming you enabled enough warnings you can expect the following being issued by the compiler:

```
warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

So the compiler seems to have noticed that those strings are "*unused*". Knowing this and being told to "optimise" the compilation those strings might very well be removed and would not use any memory at all.

If the compiler has been told to *not* optimise the strings will be part of the program and use at least `sizeof "1145" + sizeof "ho"` bytes.

Further readings:

- To [enable GCC's warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) use its `-Wxyz` options.
- To [steer optimisation with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) use its `-O` option.